# On mouse over linkText should diplay in force layout of d3.js

Tags: d3.js

At the time graph will load there will not any any linkText over the link. where as on mouse over the node(Source Node) in the graph, it should display the linkText over  the arc link of **neighboring connected nodes with source node** and on mouse out linkText should vanish again. I have created a jsfiddle [sample project](http://jsfiddle.net/ram140488/frpfnz12/4/). I am new to d3.js, need suggestion/help to implement it.

```
var linktext = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g.linklabelholder").data(force.links());

linktext.enter().append("g").attr("class", "linklabelholder")
 .append("text")
 .attr("class", "linklabel")
 .style("font-size", "13px")
 .attr("x", "50")
 .attr("y", "-20")
 .attr("text-anchor", "start")
   .style("fill","#000")
 .append("textPath")
.attr("xlink:href",function(d,i) { return "#linkId_" + i;})
 .text(function(d) { 
 return d.type; 
 });


 function mouseover(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".node").attr("r",18).style("stroke","black");
d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke","black").style("stroke-width",2);
d3.selectAll(".link").transition().duration(500)
    .style("opacity", function(o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : .1;
}); 
d3.selectAll(".node").transition().duration(500)
    .style("opacity", function(o) {
        return neighboring(d, o) ? 1 : .1;
    });}
function mouseout() {
d3.selectAll(".node").attr("r",12).style("stroke","white");
d3.selectAll(".link").attr("class", "link")
.append("line").attr("class", "link-line").style("stroke-width",1);
d3.selectAll(".link").transition().duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 1);
d3.selectAll(".node").transition().duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this first you need to add a class to the linktext so that we are able to set its opacity depending on condition.

```
linktext.enter().append("g").attr("class", "linklabelholder")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "linklabel") //setting a class
    .style("opacity", 0) //initailly making the link text invisible
    .style("font-size", "13px")
    .attr("x", "50")
    .attr("y", "-20")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "#000")
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
    return "#linkId_" + i;
})
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.type;
});
```

Now on mouse over do as below to set its opaciy depending on its connected nodes.

```
d3.selectAll(".linklabel").transition().duration(500)
    .style("opacity", function (o) {
    return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : 0;//setting the opacity
});
```

On mouse out setting the opacity as 0 so taht it becomes invisible:

```
d3.selectAll(".linklabel").transition().duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 0);
```

Simple!

Full corrected code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3j635m36/1/).